# Problems with migration from ObservableObject+Combine to Observable

Tags: swift, combine, observation

I am faced with the problem of migration from ObservableObject+Combine to Observable.

Apple has a great migration guide, and it doesn't even raise any questions. But there is no information on how to save the code from Combine.

Here is an example of a class with the ObservableObject protocol:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    var cancellable: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    init() {
        $scale
            .dropFirst()
            .debounce(for: 0.2, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { value in
                Task(){ 
                      // Code
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellable)
    }
}
```

The question is as follows - how to save constructions related to working with Combine like .sink{}, .debounce(), .store(), etc.?

I didn't find it anywhere in the documentation. So far I see only to paint the functionality using .get {} .set{}

These things are very convenient and I use them in several commercial projects. Without this, it is difficult to maintain the normal operation of business logic.

Maybe someone has encountered this?

Comment: You don't have to give up Combine just because you move from ObservableObject to Observable.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, there is no reason you *have* to give up `@Published` and `ObservableObject` if you like the pattern's semantics and are making use of it. Those technologies are built using `Combine` as an implementation detail, and it seems that you are making use of that.

The new `@Observable` does have a slightly different model. I can't find a way to expand the macro but it looks like it injects an `ObservationRegistrar` directly into the class and I surmise it cascades calls the registrar on classes in a notification chain instead of relying on a `Combine` observable.

You may also want to consider making your use of `Combine` more explicit.  Realizing that it's just sample code, the `@Published` property in your sample could be replaced by a `CurrentValueSubject` for much the same effect.

Comment: In iOS 17, there is a problem with them: If you use the ObservableObject class as a StateObject and extend it to a subview using .environmentObject, then changes to the Published properties of the class from these subviews do not lead to a call to .sink{}, etc. It breaks all logic.